# Help! zlib-1.2.9 - Killed AppArmor and all network connectivity, cannot fix

Tags: networking, wireless, kvm-virtualization, apparmor, zlib

So I was installing Flexihub (https://www.flexihub.com/download.html) and I had an error noting that the package "zlib-1.2.9" was unavailable, so I tracked it down from proper sources, installed it, and after a reboot, lost all network connectivity.

When I try to connect to a WiFi network, it will start to try and connect, then drop; the same will happen with any wired LAN connection. Most of my applications start fine, but I suddenly could not run any of my KVM virtual machines, I get the error "Error starting domain: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile" and then it lists the profile name.

I've tried to uninstall zlib-1.2.9 but it cannot find the package. Any ideas on what to do? I cannot download any fixes to the system thanks to no internet connections D:

It is Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE on a laptop, any ideas on what I can do? I would strongly prefer against reinstalling the OS as it took me ages to set up my current KDE Rice, days even.

Comment: If you installed it using apt, remove it using apt.  If you installed it another way, please describe that way.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to fix the issue by opening the Muon Package Manager, locating the package "apparmor" and marking it for re-installation. KVM machines and network connectivity are now working. I don't know if this was the best fix..but it worked for now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution!  **+1* to both Q and A!  **;-)**